# Create different header after each chapter in pages 8.2.1

Tags: pages

Can I change in Automatic way the header with the current chapter?
[image]

In Image we can see that the previous chapter (title) is in header (I text  inside the cell, not automatic way) and when begin `title 2,` the header still `title`, If I change `title` with `title 2` change the whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right side of the document window, click the 'Document' toolbar button, then the 'Section' tab.

[image]

Click somewhere in the section that you want to have a different header, then deselect the 'Match previous section' checkbox.